# How can i determine the Windows display language using Visual Basic?

Tags: windows, vb.net

I am currently working on a project, that needs multilingual support.

I need to determine the language so that the program executes the right line of code.

How would I be able to programmatically determine that?

Comment: You don't need to know the current language to provide multi-language support. If you do it right, the system handles it for you. You should research [globalisation and localisation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/globalization-localization/).

Comment: Thank you, ill look into it.

Comment: Spelling and grammar

Comment: Thank you kind sir! English is not my first language though.

Comment: Consider the CulturInfo.CurrentUICulture property.